# I am not able to append one value in JSON response

Tags: php, json, php-5.6

Here i have one JSON response, in that response i am getting values like companyId,and divisionName etc..., now i want find companyId one means i want to find what is the company name, so written one function and also i got the company name, my problems is in this name i am  not able to append same object

```
protected function getStates(){ 
        // Cross validation if the request method is GET else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
        if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
            $response_array['status']='fail';
            $response_array['message']='GET method only accept';
            $response_array['data']='';
            $this->response($this->json($response_array), 405);
        }else{
            $info_array = array(
                        "fields"=>"stateId,stateName,companyId",
                        "where"=>"stateStaus !='Inactive'"
                    );
            $state_data = $this->GetRecords("state",$info_array);
            if(count($state_data)>0) {
                $companyId = $state_data['companyId'];
                $check_info = array(
                        'fields'=>'companyName',
                        'where'=>'companyId = "'.$companyId.'" '
                    );
                $companyName = $this->GetNameById('company',$check_info);
                //$state_data['companyName'] = $companyName; //Company Name display
                $response_array['status']='success';
                $response_array['message']='Total '.count($state_data).' record(s) found.';
                $response_array['total_record']= count($state_data);
                $response_array['data']=$state_data;
                $this->response($this->json($response_array), 200);
            } else {
                $response_array['status']='fail';
                $response_array['message']='Record not found.';
                $response_array['data']='';
                $this->response($this->json($response_array), 506);
            }
        }
    }
```

> $this->response($this->json($response_array), 200); (i am getting response)

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": "Total 3 record(s) found.",
"total_record": 3,
"data": [
    {
        "stateId": "3",
        "stateName": "Odisha",
        "companyId": "1"
    },
    {
        "stateId": "2",
        "stateName": "Tamil Nadu",
        "companyId": "1"
    },
    {
        "stateId": "1",
        "stateName": "Karnadaka",
        "companyId": "1"
    }
]
}
```

For finding companyName i wrote one function **$companyName = $this->GetNameById('company',$check_info);**  here i am getting comapany name (Cibla).

> My expected results

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": "Total 3 record(s) found.",
"total_record": 3,
"data": [
    {
        "stateId": "3",
        "stateName": "Odisha",
        "companyId": "1",
        "companyName" : "Cibla"
    },
    {
        "stateId": "2",
        "stateName": "Tamil Nadu",
        "companyId": "1",
        "companyName" : "Cibla"
    },
    {
        "stateId": "1",
        "stateName": "Karnadaka",
        "companyId": "1",
        "companyName" : "Cibla"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Please reserve the use of blockquote formatting (`>`) for quotations. Do not use it to "highlight" sections. You don't need formatting there at all; this should be set in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add your company name to division data array

```
$companyName = $this->GetNameById('company',$check_info);
$response_array['status']='success';
$response_array['message']='Total '.count($division_data).' record(s) found.';
$response_array['total_record']= count($division_data);
$division_data[0]['companyName'] = $companyName; //<--------------Add this line
$response_array['data']=$division_data;
$this->response($this->json($response_array), 200);
```

**EDIT**

As you have multiple `division_data` you need to loop over them to add `companyName`

change

```
$division_data[0]['companyName'] = $companyName;
```

to

```
foreach($division_data as $key=>$divisions)
{
    $division_data[$key]['companyName'] = $companyName;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, it is not working properly,Please check my expected answer, and what i am getting answer